# Using Incron with Git for automatic backups

Tags: git, centos, incron

I'm trying to use Incron on Centos 7 to watch a directory for changes and back those changes up into a local git repo.

As a test, I've created the following:

```
/root/srv    <-- The live source directory
/root/git    <-- The backup location directory
/root/bin/git-autocommit    <-- The script that does the backup and move
```

My git-autocommit script looks like this:
    #!/bin/bash

```
REP_DIR="/root/git"       # repository directory
NOTIFY_DIR="/root/srv"    # directory to version

cd $REP_DIR
GIT_WORK_TREE=$NOTIFY_DIR /usr/bin/git add .
GIT_WORK_TREE=$NOTIFY_DIR /usr/bin/git commit -a -m "auto"
```

And I've made it executable.

I'm now trying to execute:

```
incrontab -e /root/srv IN_MODIFY,IN_CREATE,IN_MOVED_FROM,IN_MOVED_TO /root/bin/git-autocommit
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
invalid arguments - operation and source file cannot be combined
```

I can't exactly figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

it is probably too late for this answer, but adding a monitor is done in two steps

```
incrontab -e
```

will open a file and in it you will add and save the command

```
/root/srv IN_MODIFY,IN_CREATE,IN_MOVED_FROM,IN_MOVED_TO /root/bin/git-autocommit
```